# python confusion: dict.pop

Tags: python, django

I am really confused as to why Python acts in a particular way.

Here is an example: I have a dictionary called "copy". (It is a copy of an HttpRequest.POST in django.)

Here is a debug session (with added line numbers):

```
1 (Pdb) copy
2 <QueryDict: {u'text': [u'test'], u'otherId': [u'60002'], u'cmd': [u'cA'], u'id':
3  [u'15']}>
4 (Pdb) copy['text']
5  u'test'
6 (Pdb) copy.pop('text')
7  [u'test']
```

My problem is that in the dictionary it looks like the values are all lists (they come from django that way.) When I access an element as in line 4 I get it as a value rather than a list, but when I access it with pop I get it as a list again.

I am really confused by that. Can anyone help?

Comment: You should edit the title of your question: this is not an issue with Python dicts at all, but specifically with Django QueryDicts.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) for `QueryDict`s. The short answer that it is a subclass of `dict` that modifies the way you get items, so that `copy['text']` will return the *last* value in the list of values associated with `'text'`. Since they haven't overridden `pop`, it will return the entire list.

You can use [`.getlist`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to get the list associated with a particular value:

```
copy['text']
>>> u'test'

copy.getlist('text')
>>> [u'test']
```

The reason for this is that some HTML elements will return multiple values for a single key.